# alert message displays in new window

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I want to display alert message if an condition fails.so i used the following code to display the message

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("You cannot leave field empty")';
print '</script>';
```

It works fine but the problem is, it is showing message in new window with blank page as background.I need to show this message in same window.Please help to figure out a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do the validation check in Javascript in the original page, not in the submission page.

Comment: have you tried using "echo" ??

Comment: @HirenPandya Why would that make a difference?

Comment: this code is perfect, may be some other issues

Comment: Just curious. Coz I always try with that.. May be.. atleast try once and let me know the results...!!

Comment: @Svetlio: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show it on load

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'window.onload = function(){'
    print 'alert("You cannot leave field empty")';
    print '};'
print '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up the code inside if condition. Then put it in the same page where you want to show the alert..

```
if (condition) {
  print '<script type="text/javascript">';
  print 'alert("You cannot leave field empty")';
  print '</script>'; 
} else {
   //Normal flow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this in the same page of your form and don't redirect your form data to another page...(I supposed you're trying to validate a form by the alert message):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
        // do some validation for data...

        if(!valid){
               print '<script type="text/javascript">';
               print 'alert("You cannot leave field empty")';
               print '</script>';
        }

    }

    // as it's the same page of your form...all the code of form and other stuff goes           here....
    ?>


    <form action="" type="POST">
             <!-- all inputs and elements of form
    </form
```

In this way the alert will be shown in the same page of your form...if validation of submit is wrong....